# Clicking noise when starting from low speed, going over bumps

Tags: noise, suspension, echo

I have an '04 Echo that had the sway bar link replaced. However, a new annoying sound has developed. It usually happens when I'm starting from a dead stop, or going over bumps at low speeds. The sound is quite similar to when the links were completely disintegrated, but not nearly as frequent and without the swaying on the highways...

When I swapped out the snow tires, I tried to jiggle the tire, tie rod ends, the sway bar link, but didn't notice anything. I figure it could be that the links needs to be retightened, and the passenger side is a bit looser than spec, but that didn't cure it.

What else could be wrong? When I took a look at the manual, sway bar bushings looks like a very difficult job...

Comment: Could describe the sound in more detail?  Is it a consistent clicking or ticking that increases in frequency with increased road speed?  Does the sound occur when going around a corner?  Do hear it when you hit a speed bump?  Anything you can think of to add to the sound description and when it occurs will be useful in giving you an answer.

Comment: It's a click. Doesn't happen 100% of the time. When it's from dead stop, pointed straight, it's usually click once , or at most twice. Sometimes it happens while turning. No noise when i'm turning the wheel at / near dead stop (like when parallel parking)

It clicks a couple of times going over bumps. 

It doesn't happen when going at high speeds. It seems to be something in the 30km/h range.

Comment: I'm thinking bushings. I get similar from both rear shock bushings. I'll need to replace them eventually.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out it was the sway bar links. It was too cold for me to do it myself when I found out that they disintegrated, and the mechanics got a set that was short the 5th washers, which is supposed to be on the bottom side of the lower control arms.

I replaced it with a set from Febi, with the 5th washer.

So far on a test drive, there seems to be no clicking noise.